# Phonegap build for web app taking time to load

Tags: android, cordova

I have a web app for quiz and I have converted into Android app using phonegap but the problem I have is that the app takes 1-2 minutes to load which I think is because of the javascript and css being loaded. The JS and CSS files used in my quiz app are:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jQueryMobilemin.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryMobilemin.js"></script>

    <link href="css/reset.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/slickQuiz.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/master.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/slickQuiz-config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slickQuiz.js"></script>
    <script src="js/master.js"></script>
```

Is there any solution by which I can reduce the loading time of my app. I read that async JS load is better but will it help in the final android app

Comment: are you loading from a remote url?